# Depressurization of a reservoir with high pressure gas by opening a valve

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, pressure

I'm newbie in modelica and I'm trying to simulate a epressurization of a tank with high pressure hydrogen gas by opening a valve. The idea is to verify the change in flow through the valve with the decrease in pressure over time in the reservoir.

The only model that I see suitable for this is the Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume.

[image: Model screenshot]

But I having trouble to model this, because I getting this error.

The initialization finished successfully with 3 homotopy steps. The following assertion has been violated at time 5.000000 ((valveOpening.y >= 0.0 and valveOpening.y <= 1.0)) --> "Variable violating min/max constraint: 0.0 <= valveOpening.y <= 1.0, has value: 1" The arguments u_min and u_max provided in the function call solveOneNonlinearEquation(f,u_min,u_max) do not bracket the root of the single non-linear equation 0=f(u): u_min = 200 u_max = 6000 fa = f(u_min) = 11416.4 fb = f(u_max) = 1.04699e+08 fa and fb must have opposite sign which is not the case Process crashed

Is this the best way to solve my problem?

Comment: Please copy and paste the entire error message here instead of posting an image.

Comment: Paste the error message in the question, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the error message, it seems you have configured `valveOpening` to output values greater than one. This violates the `max` condition in this line

```
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput opening(min=0,max=1)
```

of the valve (`Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear`).

Unfortunately, it is not possible to be sure that this is the error as you didn't post code for the model...

Comment: You right. I change the condition to open the valve and it work perfectly.